# "Straight" or "linear" helix

Tags: terminology, biophysics, nomenclature, structural-biology

If an alpha helix is discontinued for a short while and then continues in a different direction, I prefer to call in "kinked". If the helix is simply uniformly following one direction, I prefer to call it "straight", but I have been corrected, and been told that it is called "linear". Which is right?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please read the [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [Help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions. There you will see that you should demonstrate that you have tried to research a question yourself before asking, especially apposite in this case as this sort of terminology is merely a question of convention. In fact there is no right or wrong, just clarity of expression.

Comment: OK, let me put you out of your misery. You have a basic misconception. The first image is not of **an** alpha-helix, but **two**. It could be a helix-turn-helix. And so the terms straight and linear are superfluous. Anyway, I’d avoid “straight” for the lower one, unless you wish to consider changing “kinked” to…

Comment: Okay.. Thanks, but I guess my question is unclear. Yes - it is two helices, it it is not really the helix the is kinked, that is true. It is the conformation I want to describe, a "kinked conformation" vs a "straight conformation" of a protein segment.

Comment: Read about protein secondary structure to learn how it is described. You are trying to reinvent the wheel and getting it square.